# Adjusting test size of K-Fold Cross Validation

Tags: python, machine-learning, random-forest, cross-validation

I am looking to use k-fold cross validation on a random forest regressor in Python.  I understand that k refers to the number of folds in the data-set, but how can I adjust the test-set size? Say I wanted to split the data in ten different ways, but in each fold I wanted the data split 50/50, how would I do this? Here is what i currently have;

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import cross_val_predict
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor as rfr

<wasn't sure how to include the data as its a big file>

# BUILD RANDOM FOREST MODEL
rfmodel = rfr(n_estimators = 100, random_state = 0)

# make cross validated predictions
cv_preds = cross_val_predict(rfmodel, x, y, cv=10)
cv_preds = (np.around(cv_preds, 2))
```

I'm aware that k-fold is not necessarily needed for RF, however for the purposes of this project that is what I need to do.

EDIT:  I'll try to re-articulate as I probably haven't described my problem well enough. Say I have 100 observations with k=5, instead of dividing observations into five equal-sized folds, training on k-1 and testing on the remaining fold, what I am looking to do is to randomly allocate the 100 observations into a 50/50 train-test split, run the model, and then re-allocate the 100 observations into another 50/50 split and run the model again. I would then do this 5 times.

Comment: i think you have a problem inn your understanding of k fold, you dont specify the test size, you specify K, it divides the dataset into k partitions, and random k-1 partitions are used as training set and a random set is used as the test partition, you cant dictate the test size,

Comment: "I wanted to split the data in ten different ways, but in each fold I wanted the data split 50/50 " or  are you saying that you want to split the first half of the 50/50 split into 10 different ways?

Comment: Read about `sklearn.model_selection.RepeatedKFold`here http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.RepeatedKFold.html#sklearn-model-selection-repeatedkfold

Comment: That could be just the trick Rahul, thanks